# How to make Action Bar font bigger

Tags: nativescript

In my iOS Nativescript app, I would like to make the font-size on the ActionBar (ie, the navigation toolbar header) larger. This is especially relevant for publishing an app to a tablet, where it looks small in the default setting.

Is there a way for me to do this? Especially with the iOS "back" button?

I have figured out that the following does in fact increase the font:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <ActionItem  ios.position="right">
        <Label text="hello" style="font-size: 35pt;"></Label>
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

But: While this would make the word "hello" in the action bar larger, this will not change the font of the iOS **back** button that appears in order to navigate back away from the page. I do not think there is specific html that can target that back button (it is "hidden" from the html code).

So I would need a solution that allows you to make everything in the ActionBar larger, or else some way that I can additionally target the back button to make it bigger.

Is there a way for me to do either of these?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the default back button font size, instead you could hide the `NavigationButton` by setting `visibility` to `hidden` and place an `ActionItem` on the left with a custom `Label` with font size of your choice. Upon clicking that, you will have to trigger the back navigation on your frame.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, a custom back label will have different navigation functionality and it has ripple effects on the other navigation of the app. The default back button does not always go to the prior page, and has a particular navigation scheme. Replacing that with a custom label at least requires adjusting that page's navigation and the navigation of other pages, taking into account earlier navigation. In any event, I appreciate the suggestion as maybe the only option anyway.

Comment: ```goBack(): void { this.routerExtensions.back(); }```   this is the same functionality as the back button,  not sure what you mean when you say a custom back button and the default back button are different if they both perform back on the router.

Comment: Thanks--I will check it out. What I meant: if I do a custom function instead of the back function, and when that custom function is called navigate to a particular page, THAT is a different action than the default back button performs. With custom function, the navigated to page's back button would lead to prior page. With default back button, the navigated to page's back button would lead to whatever page came before it the first time it loaded. so custom navigation has different navigation effects than default back button. But hopefully your code mimics default back button.

Comment: @Zuriel your method works. Thanks very much. Only remaining piece is proper CSS to properly mimick the way the '<' looks on iOS.